# How to see if a value is between two values with a name

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, range

Let's say I have a range called A, and it is integers between 6-10 and I have a range called B for integers between 11-15. I have a function that is going to return an integer and I want to quickly determine if the integer is in range A, B or .....many more. What is the best way to do this?

I thought a dictionary at first, but that would allow me to have the name "A" or "B" and one integer. I need the name and two integers. Or is there a better way to approach this? I'll have over 100 ranges when it's done.